# How to list shared folders from "My Drive"

Tags: google-drive-api

On Google Drive web application, "My Drive" contains following folders

- A (owner: me, shared: true)
- B (owner: not me, shared: true)
- C (owner: me, shared: false)

When I try to get files.list with query "parents in 'root' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", I obtain only "C" folder.

How to get "A" and "C" folders in the query result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following patterns for the query?

#### Pattern 1 :

`or sharedWithMe` was added. In my environment, the folders of A, B and C on root can be retrieved by this query.

```
parents in 'root' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' or sharedWithMe
```

#### Pattern 2 :

For "A (owner: me, shared: true)", I'm not sure whether this folder is at root. So can you try this query?

```
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' or sharedWithMe
```

#### Reference :

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/query-ref)

If these were not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: `'root' in parents and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` is the correct expression.

Comment: @sestegra I couldn't notice about 'root' in parents. I'm really sorry I couldn't be useful for you. And thank you for your additional information.

Comment: @sestegra Thank you for your concern. I'll keep studying, and work hard.